# automation anywhere - as400 field exit key

Tags: automation

I am working with as400 green screens, I have a field where I need to enter combination of alpha-numerics and do a field exit followed by entered key. I am not able to find the key option that needs to be pressed for field exit in automation anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are using the PCOMM standard emulator or the Java client, you can actually configure which keys are used for field exit.

Standard PCOMM usually uses the + on the number pad.

With the Java version, click the Remap Keyboard Functions icon:
[image]

Then you can select Host Functions from the drop down. Scroll down till you find Field Exit.

[image]